# Cannot add to favourites in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

I cannot add any website to my favourites in Microsoft Edge. It just shows a grayed out button. See image (sorry its in German, but you get the idea).

[image]

Helpfully, it also doesn't show a tooltip, so I have no idea why I cannot add the website.

Comment: What is Hinzufugen? Abbrechen? Farfegnugen?

Comment: Hinzufugen = 'Add', Abbrechen = 'Cancel', not sure about 'Farfegnugen'

Comment: Farfegnugen is a joke, by Volkswagen in the 90's. Did you try just clicking the "star" icon from the browser?

Comment: that's "fahrvergnügen" :) It sort of lets me add to favourite by just pressing the star. But why then pop up that window?!? Showing my favourites in a toolbar is also another thing that I can't get to work. This seems also to be confusing as hell to do. Nothing is clear from a usability perspective. I think they hired all the fired UI Developers from 'Windows 8' to build this thing.

Comment: I just logged into my Surface Pro4, which has Windows 10. I don't use Edge, but I opened it and it let me add favorites just as you are trying. I am thinking about "favorites" or "shortcuts". Try this. Log out and just go to "stackoverflow.com". Just that, no stackoverflow.com/...?=.... Maybe it could be a "handshake" for favorites between browser(you) and server(stackoverflow)? For example: (I am a website, you may "favorite me" at my index page, but nowhere else -- and Edge acknowledges this agreement).